# Do you have any resource explaining how to use Firebase Test lab with GitLab pipeline?

Tags: android, docker, gitlab-ci, fastlane, firebase-test-lab

I want to run my instrumentation tests with espresso in the Firebase Test Lab with every commit to a branch in GitLab. I already build, deploy and release the app using Docker and Fastlane but I can't find anything on google that integrates the test lab with any of these tools. Do you guys know anything about this that I can use to achieve running the instrumentation tests with the CI system of GitLab?

Comment: You're saying you can't use the gcloud command line to run a test?

Comment: I can use it, but I don't know where to put it when using gitlab. I was able to run the tests with gcloud following the firebase documentation in jenkins in a test project. However, the real project is hosted in gitlab and I'm expected to set it to run the tests automatically.

Answer (score 2):

We've recently partnered with Google Firebase to add this feature to Buddybuild. Basically, if you onboard your application, we'll run your instrumentation tests on real devices using FTL. More information can be found here: https://www.buddybuild.com/blog/running-android-ui-tests-on-physical-devices

Happy to answer any further question you might have!

Answer (score 1):

Test Lab can be invoked from a CI system using gcloud. There are instructions on how to do this for [Jenkins](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/continuous) and [Circle CI](http://circleci.com/docs/1.0/google-cloud-test-lab/).

There is also a Slack channel for Test Lab users. Join via https://firebase.community and find the #test-lab channel. Several of the users there have successfully connected Test Lab to their CI systems.

Answer (score 0):

After a while and gaining more experience with docker, I found how to install and set up gcloud with a service account in a container. The commands were right in [google's gcloud image's](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker/blob/master/debian/Dockerfile) Dockerfile. I just copied them into my Dockerfile as I didn't want to use their image but have gcloud CLI in mine.

Also following [gcloud's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/) I could build the command to login with a service account without user interaction. The only thing needed is to copy the keyfile.json to the container.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account $GOOGLE_AUTH_EMAIL --key-file /path-to/keyfile.json --project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID
```

Finally, here's the portion I added to the original Dockerfile:

```
ENV GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID "yetanothertest-91d46"
ENV GOOGLE_AUTH_EMAIL "docker@yetanothertest91d46.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
ENV GOOGLE_KEY "keyfile.json"

ADD keyfile.json /home

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qqy \
curl gcc python-dev python-setuptools apt-transport-https lsb-release  && \
easy_install -U pip && \
pip install -U crcmod

RUN export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)" && \
echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

RUN curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk

RUN apt-get -y remove gcc python-dev python-setuptools

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN gcloud config set core/disable_usage_reporting true && \
gcloud config set component_manager/disable_update_check true

RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account $GOOGLE_AUTH_EMAIL --key-file /home/keyfile.json --project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID
```

What's left to do is add the gcloud commands in Fastlane (as it's being used to run all the testing/building/deployment tasks) to send the apks to firebase along with the devices that will be used for the tests.